# How to set timeouts for queues properly?

Tags: php, multithreading, queue, beanstalkd

I wrote my consumer for the Beanstalkd queue, running it with Supervisord.

```
php5.5-sp %appdir%/worker
```

`worker` is a PHP file, looping with 1 seconds sleep duration. Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

    while(true)
    {
         echo time() . PHP_EOL;
         exec("php5.5-sp -d max_execution_time=30 job");
         sleep(1);
    }
```

`job` (file) uses Beanstalkd, pops a job, attempts to process it.

```
 // job
 require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
 # Initialize beanstalkd
 $beanstalkd = new Illuminate\Queue\Worker($queue->getQueueManager(), null, null);
 try {
     $beanstalkd ->pop('default', 'default', 2, 8192);
 } catch (Exception $e) {
     Log::critical($e->getMessage());
 }
```

The `queue` is like this:

```
<?php namespace Aristona\Queue;

class ArticleParserService
{

     public function fire($job, Array $data)
     {
          // Do some time taking stuff
     }
}
```

Everything works properly. The problem is, sometimes I expect a timeout (e.g The site I try to fetch has a redirection loop) but the queue just keeps running forever. Since it doesn't stop, the rest of the queues are getting blocked.

I tried:

1. Adding `-d max_execution_time=30`, no effect.
2. Setting `max_execution_time` on Queue, no effect.
3. Setting `ttr` to 30 seconds on Beanstalkd configuration, no effect.

I don't know what else I should be doing?

Logs are like this:

```
sudo supervisord > tail -f queue
Worker is looping on [production] at 1425389013...
Worker is looping on [production] at 1425389016...
Worker is looping on [production] at 1425389017...
Worker is looping on [production] at 1425389019...
Worker is looping on [production] at 1425389023...
Worker is looping on [production] at 1425389027... (stuck here forever)

vi debug.log
DEBUG - 2015-03-03 08:23:59 :: There is no image in the feed. Attempting to guess it.
DEBUG - 2015-03-03 08:23:59 :: Guessing image from URL: https://www.aksent-tercume.com/di%c4%9fer-diller/212-dilde-seni-seviyorum-de/
DEBUG - 2015-03-03 08:24:01 :: Guessed an appropriate image!
DEBUG - 2015-03-03 08:24:01 :: Validating image size...
```

The part with "Validating image size..." where everything stops forever, and it is always in the same URL. (https://www.aksent-tercume.com/di%c4%9fer-diller/212-dilde-seni-seviyorum-de/)

All the script does is connecting to an URL, finding the most appropriate image for the article, then checking it's size to make sure it is bigger than 60x60 pixel. But for some reason, it just halts there, blocking our queues forever. I cannot get it to timeout. Only the following makes queues back to normal.

```
sudo service beanstalkd restart
sudo supervisorctl > restart all
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be more of a case of the script not using a HTTP client that can set an appropriate timeout in the underlying library (which would probably be libCurl), not the top-level system.

The PHP code calls some web-client, which may be calling a C-based library, that opens a network connection, which is failing.

If the connection to Beanstalkd is still open, it is probably failing the TTR, as that is separate to the PHP instance and code, but if the script is stuck, it doesn't help you.

You probably need a better HTTP client that can generate a timeout for itself, to catch that, and delete, or bury the job.

In the meantime, if there's a single URL that fails - just don't do anything with that, delete it if you see it.